# Injecting the Router and the ActivatedRouteSnapshot into an Angular 15 router guard?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular15

I'm trying to convert a pre Angular 15 Router Guard to a Router Guard Function.

The current version looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TopicGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    const topicStore: EStore<Topic> = route.data[TOPIC_STORE_KEY]
    const id = route.paramMap.get("topic")
    const topic = topicStore.findOneByID(id || '')
    if (topic) {
      return true
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/404'])
    return false
  }
}
```

It injects the `Router` and gets the `route` via the `canActivate` method.

To convert this to the functional version can we just do something like this:

```
export function topicGuard(router: Router, route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) { ... }
```

Is that the correct way to inject the dependencies into the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use [inject()](https://angular.io/api/core/inject)

```
import {inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {tap} from 'rxjs';
import {SomeOtherService} from '../some-other-service.service';

export const myGuard= () => {
    const router = inject(Router);
    const service = inject(SomeOtherService)
    return service.isAllowed().pipe(
    tap((allowed) => {
      if(allowed){
         return true;
      } else {
        router.navigate(['/nope'])
      }
    }
  ))
}
```